# jQuery ajax-upload from valums.com not working in Opera and IE when with other scripts

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, ajax-upload

I'm building a profile page where the user will be able to upload and remove profile pictures. There are some more scripts included on this page. I was unpleasantly surprised that not everything works in IE and Opera. They do work fine when separate. The url is http://velo.smspoetry.net/problem/ . Can you please point me in what directions to look for.

Problem description:
IE: nothing happens when plus sign is pressed below the thumbnails.
Opera: when the plus sign is pressed the browse window opens but does not upload the picture and none of the code in onSubmit is executed.
Firefox and Chrome work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id that triggered that functionality when clicked was assigned to an A tag, when assigned to an image works fine.